# Using submit and text to pass a value to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am a begginer with asp.net mvc 3.  I want to create a page where an user can enter a search item and retrieve the data from database.  I have created the database.  I have created the controller which is:

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string id)
{
    string searchString=id;
    var search = from m in db.Searches
    select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        search = search.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
    }

    return View(search);
}
```

I want to pass the value from view page to the above controller.  What should be the code in view page to enter an item to search from above mentioned controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So create your view with a form inside... something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label>Search:</label>
    <input type="text" name="searchString" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
}
```

Then in your controller you can use the FormCollection object to grab your searchString like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchIndex(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    string searchString = formCollection["searchString"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: what are arguements to be present inside @using (Html.BeginForm())?